# Override tomcat properties on tomcat level

Tags: java, tomcat, systemd, properties-file

Currently my application is able to resolve application properties using two strategies:

- Internal: This strategy will use `application.properites` file from code base.
- External properties: This strategy can use `application.properites` file in case it exist in `config` folder on tomcat level.

For instance: if tomcat is started in following way `/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`. Code will look up external properties by following path `/opt/tomcat/bin/config/application.properites`

This approach works fine if application is started in following way `sh /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`, but it doesn't work with systemd unit tomcat file `service tomcat start`.

There is content of `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` unit file

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried to copy my config folder to `/etc/systemd/system/`, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas which path will be correct for `config` folder using systemd script.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? What error do you get?

Comment: I've just fixed it. It didn't work when I've started tomcat with following command service tomcat start. Actually external property file wasn't load instead internal property was used.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it with following line in unit file:

```
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tomcat/bin
```